# Is calloc exactly the same as malloc + memset?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, glibc

In linux, is calloc exactly the same as malloc + memset or does this depend on the exact linux/kernel version?

I am particularly interested in the question of whether you can calloc more RAM than you physically have (as you can certainly malloc more RAM than you physically have, you just can't write to it).  In other words, does calloc always actually write to the memory you have been allocated as the specs suggest it should.

Comment: `calloc` and `malloc` are not kernel operations, they're just C library functions.

Comment: @Barmar True but where is the "optimistic memory allocation strategy" implemented? In the library or kernel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why malloc+memset is slower than calloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc)

Comment: @Barmar they not are not just C library functions as they call syscalls.

Comment: @ouah: traditionally, the system call underlying `malloc()` et al was `sbrk()`, which is not a POSIX standard system call.  I don't know whether Linux has actual system calls for the memory management functions, but it seems unlikely since you can use alternative libraries for memory allocation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler *glibc* and like use [Doug Lea's malloc.c](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8aJdhhEBFsEJ:ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c&hl=en&gl=ca&strip=1) or a derivative.  It uses `sbrk()` and `mmap()` for large regions.  And `mremap()` for an efficient `realloc()` on Linux.  Doug Lea is currently/recently working on Java's GC.

Comment: At one point *glibc* malloc, etc was as per Doug Lea.  [Here is a more current version](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=897c43a39d963580f701518c9ecc1cc7b9275942;hb=HEAD) of the *glibc* allocator.  It is much the same, but is not 100% identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, that depends on the implementation, but on a modern day Linux, you probably can. Easiest way is to try it, but I'm saying this based on the following logic.

You can `malloc` more than the memory you have (physical + virtual) because the kernel delays allocation of your memory until you actually use it. I believe that's to increase the chances of your program not failing due to memory limits, but that's not the question.

`calloc` is the same as `malloc` but zero initializes the memory. When you ask Linux for a page of memory, Linux already zero-initializes it. So if `calloc` can tell that the memory it asked for was just requested from the kernel, it doesn't actually have to zero initialize it! Since it doesn't, there is no access to that memory and therefore it should be able to request more memory than there actually is.

As mentioned in the comments [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2688522/912144) provides a very good explanation.

Comment: @tux3, if you were in kernel space, you can do anything. The question is regarding user space where `malloc` and `calloc` functions are available. If you _could_ get non-initialized pages from the kernel in your user application, that would have been a serious security bug.

Answer (score 2):

Whether `calloc` needs to write to the memory depends on whether it got the allocation from heap pages that are already assigned to the process, or it had to request more memory be assigned to the process by the kernel (using a system call such as `sbrk()` or `mmap()`). When the kernel assigns new memory to a process, it always zeroes it first (typically using a VM optimization, so it doesn't actually have to write to the page). But if it's reusing memory that was assigned previously, it has to use `memset()` to zero it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not mentioned in the [cited duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688466/why-mallocmemset-is-slower-than-calloc) or here.  Linux uses *virtual memory* and can allocate more memory that physically available in the system.  A naive implementation of `calloc()` that simply does a `malloc()` plus `memset()` in user space will touch every page.

As Linux typically allocates in 4k chunks, all of the `calloc()` blocks are the same and initially read as zero.  That is the same 4k chunk of memory can be mapped **read only** and the entire `calloc()` space in only taking up approximately `size/4k * pointer_size + 4k`.  As the program writes to the `calloc()` space, a page fault happens and Linux will allocate a new page (4k) and resume the program.

This is called [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) or **COW** for short.  `malloc()` will generally behave the same way.  For small sizes, [the 'C' library](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) will use *binning* and share 4k pages with other small sized allocation.

So, there are typically two layers involved.

1. Linux kernel's process memory management.
2. *glibc* heap management.

If the memory size requested is large and requires new memory allocated to the process, then most of the above applies (via Linux's process memory management).  However, if the memory requested is small, then it will be like a `malloc()` plus `memset()`.  In the large allocation size, the `memset()` is damaging as it touches the memory and the kernel thinks it needs a new page to allocate.

Comment: `calloc()` can be advantageous to allocate large sparse arrays.  Especially if the *occupied* chunks are clustered, like Unicode pages, etc.  Only 4k pages where *non-zero* data is used need to be physically allocated.

Comment: The 4k number is `malloc_getpagesize()` in dlmalloc.  You can also use `sysconf(PAGESIZE);`, [`getpagesize()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html), etc.  On some systems, this is 8k.

Comment: See also: [Linux Zero page (BSS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115434/linux-will-zeroed-page-pagefault-on-first-read-or-on-first-write), [Ulrich Drepper's Linux VMM](http://lwn.net/Articles/253361/), [Memory FAQ](http://landley.net/writing/memory-faq.txt), [lxr empty_zero_page](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=empty_zero_page).

Answer (score 0):

You can't `malloc(3)` more ram than the kernel gives the process doing the `malloc(3)`-ing. `malloc(3)` returns NULL if you can't allocate the amount of memory you want to allocate. In addition, `malloc(3)` and `memset(3)` are defined by your c library (`libc.so`) and not your kernel. The Linux kernel defines `mmap(2)` and other low-level memory allocation functions, not the `*alloc(3)` family (excluding `kalloc()`).