# Arithmetic Template Swap faster than std::swap?

Tags: c++, optimization

I looked around and combined a basic temporary variable swap with a type template restricted to arithmetic types. Why is this faster than `std::swap`?

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void swp(T& x, T& y) {
    T t = x; x = y; y = t;
}
```

Here is the specific implementation I am using for testing: (try clearing the cache for testing consistency, see [this post for info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34461372/2808956))

```
int main() {
    const size_t bigger_than_cachesize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    long* p = new long[bigger_than_cachesize];
    for (int i = 0; i < bigger_than_cachesize; i++) p[i] = rand();
    std::cout << "Cache is flushed..." << std::endl;
    /// IGNORE ABOVE (ATTEMPTING TO CLEAR CACHE FOR CONSISTENCY)

    double duration;
    int x = 2560, y = 435;
    std::clock_t start;
    start = std::clock();

    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) std::swap(x,y);

    duration = (std::clock() - start);
    std::cout << "std::swap: " << duration << '\n';
    duration = 0;
    start = std::clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) swp(x,y);

    duration = (std::clock() - start);
    std::cout << "swapTMP: " << duration << '\n';
}
```

Results: (5:1 ratio)

```
std::swap -> 5086
<T> swp   -> 1397
```

Comment: Please show a [mre] with your full code, compiler settings and performance measurements

Comment: The compiler is likely optimizing your arithmetic swap without actually using temporary variables. One would hope that a *decent* `std::swap()` implementation would already be optimized for arithmetic types.

Comment: What do you mean by _seem to be faster_? What experiment did you design. How did you measure runtime? Which compiler, optimizations, architecture, ...?

Comment: @DanielLangr x64, VS compiler, standard optimizations.

Comment: I don't understand your experiment. You allocate a large array but then measure swapping of two local variables. Both loop have no effect in the end and may be completely optimized away by the compiler. And, also are with optimizations: https://godbolt.org/z/rxv7Px. Moreover, subtracting results of `std::clock` does not give you milliseconds.

Comment: @DanielLangr I added missing comments, my apologies...

Comment: @FatalSleep What are _standard optimizations_? It seems the they are disabled. Measuring performance without enabled optimizations does not make any sense.

Comment: @DanielLangr whatever VS2019 uses by default for console applications.

Comment: I can only reproduce your results in VS2017 by using a debug build, in a release build both measurements are 31 ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on assembly of this simple code, when optimizations are enabled (`-O2`).

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

int foo(int a, int b) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) std::swap(a, b);
    return a;
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void swp(T& x, T& y) {
    T t = x; x = y; y = t;
}

int bar(int a, int b) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) swp(a, b);
    return a;
}
```

Here is [godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/qW4bY8).

Machine code for `foo` and `bar` are exact the same when compared for each compiler.

What is more important `msvc` was able to optimize away `for` loops detecting that they do not introduce any visible outcome ("as if" rule).

So since you have different results this means you are testing that incorrectly.

Remember that testing performance such small and fast functions like `swap` is extremely hard from technical point of view and it is easy to do mistake which will lead to wrong conclusions.

Basically it looks like you have reach limit of time resolution of `std::clock()`.

Comment: If I include the for loop for adjusting the `x,y` variables then the compiler can't optimize it away. Right?

Comment: In this case the compiler can't really optimize away the for loop anyways? Since each loop the values are swapped, there shouldn't be anything for the compiler to do.

Comment: @FatalSleep After the loop, the values of swapped variables are the same as before the loop. So yes, a compiler can completely optimized loops away. I suggest to learn more about optimizations and the "as-if" rule before making such experiments.

Comment: Please provide details: compiler, how you build it and how you run it.

Comment: @MarekR pretty basic, default console app settings in VS2019. Haven't changed a thing.

Comment: @FatalSleep Is it a Debug or Release build?

Comment: @Blastfurnace debug and release. Though as Marek mentioned... voila, optimized away. Problem solved.

Comment: Here is your full code: https://www.godbolt.org/z/hvaYYE loops because of size its harder to read, but you can find that loops has been removed.