# Flushing cache with Google Benchmark

Tags: c++, caching, benchmarking, microbenchmark, google-benchmark

I want to compare the performance of two algorithms on a large inputs. The primary difference between the algorithms is that one *should* have better cache access patterns than the other. I want the size of the input to be much larger than the L3 cache, so the input will exceed 64 MB.

The algorithms are implemented as `func1` and `func2`. I would implement the test as

```
std::vector<int> input_1 = GetRandomInput();
std::vector<int> input_2 = input_1;

double func1_runtime = Benchmark(func1, input_1);
std::cout << "func1s runtime was " << func1_runtime << "\n";

double func2_runtime = Benchmark(func2, input_2);
std::cout << "func2s runtime was " << func2_runtime << "\n";
```

I'm trying to find a function `Benchmark` that will attempt to clear all of the data out of cache prior to running. Is there any such function in Google Benchmark?

Comment: Doesn't `Benchmark(func1, input_1)` run func1 *multiple times*, to make the timed interval long enough to hide measurement noise and CPU / page-fault warm-up effects?  If so, it wouldn't make sense to evict input_1 from cache just once before running it.  But if you only run once, then see [Flushing the cache to prevent benchmarking fluctiations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49077734) and [Is there a way to flush the entire CPU cache related to a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48533834)

Comment: @PeterCordes I considered rolling my own, but I didn't understand step 3 in your first link, and hoped some library like Google Benchmark had solved this problem since 2018.

Comment: Step 3 is like `volatile void *sink = ptr;`, or especially `sink = ptr` with a global `sink` to make the variable obviously globally reachable.